# How to get calculated values from hidden fields in a dynamic form in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Right now I'm doing a form in Angular 8 that is database driven. The form changes depending on the parameters found in the DB (validation, number of questions, type of questions, etc). The goal is to not have to change anything on the frontend when the form requirements change.

Among the questions, there are hidden inputs whose input depends on the answers of the other questions. Depending on some answers, the hidden input value can change and even new questions can appear.

How should I observe this changes to be able to show new questions and/or calculate the hidden input values?

Comment: Please include the code you have tried, or provide stackblitz link for your question, or search "dynamic form angular"

Comment: If you're using reactive forms, you most likely won't need these hidden fields as you can observe changes to your form group as a whole or individual fields to determine what to show or calculate next.